# Unix sort issue

Tags: sorting, unix

Can somebody explain why UNIX sort output differs when delimiter is comma',' and pipe '|'

I know that I am applying numeric sort on alphanumeric column but I think output should not differ when delimiter is either comma or pipe.

File with comma delimiter:

```
$cat file.txt
1,1400002827,002,DC19183529
2,1400002827,002,DC19183500
3,1400004243,001,DC17458621
4,1400008953,004,1459345892
5,1600009991,001,DC17458621
6,1600009991,001,DC17458621
7,1600009991,001,DC17458659
8,1600009991,003,DC17458789

$sort -t, -nuk2,4 file.txt 
1,1400002827,002,DC19183529
3,1400004243,001,DC17458621
5,1600009991,001,DC17458621
8,1600009991,003,DC17458789
4,1400008953,004,1459345892
```

Modified same file to have delimiter as pipe '|'

```
$cat file.txt
1|1400002827|002|DC19183529
2|1400002827|002|DC19183500
3|1400004243|001|DC17458621
4|1400008953|004|1459345892
5|1600009991|001|DC17458621
6|1600009991|001|DC17458621
7|1600009991|001|DC17458659
8|1600009991|003|DC17458789

$sort -t'|' -nuk2,4 file.txt
1|1400002827|002|DC19183529
3|1400004243|001|DC17458621
4|1400008953|004|1459345892
5|1600009991|001|DC17458621
```

I don't need alternate solution.
I need to understand why `sort` gives different output with comma and pipe.

Comment: Testing with other symbols makes me think there's something about numerical separators, becasue I get the same result with '.' dot as with ',', but if I put for instance ';' it's the same as with pipes. Also note that the `-k` option is only taking the 2, if you remove `,4` you still get the same result.

Comment: Just to explain on my comment just before, because I was mistaken: `-k2,4` is sorting from column `2` to `4`, which in this case is the same as `-k2` which is from column `2` until the end.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this problem has [shown up before](https://superuser.com/questions/466956/sorting-numerically-in-a-comma-delimited-file-with-unix).

`sort` is taking commas as thousand separators because of the `-n` option.  That's why your result with commas does not match the result with other separators. Apparently it also happens with `.`. If you want alphanumeric sort and remove the `-n` option, the result is the same for both `|` and `,`.

```
sort -t'|' -uk2,2 pipes.txt 
1|1400002827|002|DC19183529
3|1400004243|001|DC17458621
4|1400008953|004|1459345892
5|1600009991|001|DC17458621

sort -t',' -uk2,2 commas.txt 
1,1400002827,002,DC19183529
3,1400004243,001,DC17458621
4,1400008953,004,1459345892
5,1600009991,001,DC17458621
```